# Efficient summation in OCaml

Tags: performance, ocaml, pi

Please note I am almost a complete newbie in OCaml. In order to learn a bit, and test its performance, I tried to implement a module that approximates Pi using the [Leibniz series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_series).

My first attempt led to a stack overflow (the actual error, not this site).  Knowing from Haskell that this may come from too many "thunks", or promises to compute something, while recursing over the addends, I looked for some way of keeping just the last result while summing with the next.  I found the following tail-recursive implementations of `sum` and `map` in the notes of an OCaml course, [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa11/cse130-a/static/tailrecursion.pdf) and [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi11/cse130/discussion/ocaml-fold.pdf), and expected the compiler to produce an efficient result.

However, the resulting executable, compiled with `ocamlopt`, is much slower than a C++ version compiled with `clang++`. Is this code as efficient as possible? Is there some optimization flag I am missing?

My complete code is:

```
let (--) i j =
  let rec aux n acc =
    if n < i then acc else aux (n-1) (n :: acc)
    in aux j [];;


let sum_list_tr l =
  let rec helper a l = match l with
    | [] -> a
    | h :: t -> helper (a +. h) t
  in helper 0. l


let rec tailmap f l a = match l with
  | [] -> a
  | h :: t -> tailmap f t (f h :: a);;


let rev l =
    let rec helper l a = match l with
      | [] -> a
      | h :: t -> helper t (h :: a)
    in helper l [];;


let efficient_map f l = rev (tailmap f l []);;


let summand n =
  let m = float_of_int n
  in (-1.) ** m /. (2. *. m +. 1.);;


let pi_approx n =
  4. *. sum_list_tr (efficient_map summand (0 -- n));;


let n = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1);;
Printf.printf "%F\n" (pi_approx n);;
```

Just for reference, here are the measured times on my machine:

```
❯❯❯ time ocaml/main 10000000
3.14159275359
ocaml/main 10000000  3,33s user 0,30s system 99% cpu 3,625 total

❯❯❯ time cpp/main 10000000
3.14159
cpp/main 10000000  0,17s user 0,00s system 99% cpu 0,174 total
```

For completeness, let me state that the first helper function, an equivalent to Python's `range`, comes [from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243864/what-is-the-ocaml-idiom-equivalent-to-pythons-range-function), and that this is run using OCaml version 4.01.0, installed via MacPorts on a Darwin 13.1.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, OCaml's `float` are boxed, which puts OCaml to a disadvantage compared to Clang.

However, I may be noticing another typical rough edge trying OCaml after Haskell: 
if I see what your program is doing, you are creating a list of stuff, to then map a function on that list and finally fold it into a result.

In Haskell, you could more or less expect such a program to be automatically “[deforested](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/deforest/deforest.ps)” at compile-time, so that the resulting generated code was an efficient implementation of the task at hand.

In OCaml, the fact that functions can have side-effects, and in particular functions passed to high-order functions such as map and fold, means that it would be much harder for the compiler to deforest automatically. The programmer has to do it by hand.

In other words: stop building huge short-lived data structures such as `0 -- n` and `(efficient_map summand (0 -- n))`. When your program decides to tackle a new summand, make it do all it wants to do with that summand in a single pass. You can see this as an exercise in applying the principles in Wadler's article (again, by hand, because for various reasons the compiler will not do it for you despite your program being pure).

---

Here are some results:

```
$ ocamlopt v2.ml
$ time ./a.out 1000000
3.14159165359

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.003s
$ ocamlopt v1.ml
$ time ./a.out 1000000
3.14159365359

real    0m0.238s
user    0m0.204s
sys     0m0.029s
```

v1.ml is your version. v2.ml is what you might consider an idiomatic OCaml version:

```
let rec q_pi_approx p n acc =
  if n = p
  then acc
  else q_pi_approx (succ p) n (acc +. (summand p))

let n = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1);;

Printf.printf "%F\n" (4. *. (q_pi_approx 0 n 0.));;
```

(reusing `summand` from your code)

It might be more accurate to sum from the last terms to the first, instead of from the first to the last. This is orthogonal to your question, but you may consider it as an exercise in modifying a function that has been forcefully made tail-recursive. Besides, the `(-1.) ** m` expression in `summand` is mapped by the compiler to a call to the `pow()` function on the host, and that's [a bag of hurt](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/06/Non-experts-need-accurate-floating-point-the-most) you may want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks, a very interesting answer, pointing out details I was totally unaware of.  I will have to read Wadler's article and try to produce another version that does not "map over a big list".  If that leads to better time results, I will accept your answer as the solution!

Comment: I imagine that the first `ocamlopt v1.ml` should read `ocamlopt v2.ml`?

Comment: I see you have posted a complete answer.  Just tried that on my machine and, indeed, it is faster than the clang-C++ combo.  I am very impressed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

I've also tried several variants, here are my conclusions:

1. Using arrays
2. Using recursion
3. Using imperative loop

Recursive function is about 30% more effective than array implementation. Imperative loop is approximately as much effective as a recursion (maybe even little slower).

Here're my implementations:

### Array:

```
open Core.Std

let pi_approx n =
  let f m = (-1.) ** m /. (2. *. m +. 1.) in
  let qpi = Array.init n ~f:Float.of_int |>
            Array.map ~f |>
            Array.reduce_exn ~f:(+.) in
  qpi *. 4.0
```

### Recursion:

```
let pi_approx n =
  let rec loop n acc m =
    if m = n
    then acc *. 4.0
    else
      let acc = acc +. (-1.) ** m /. (2. *. m +. 1.) in
      loop n acc (m +. 1.0) in
  let n = float_of_int n in
  loop n 0.0 0.0
```

This can be further optimized, by moving local function `loop` outside, so that compiler can inline it.

### Imperative loop:

```
let pi_approx n =
  let sum = ref 0. in
  for m = 0 to n -1 do
    let m = float_of_int m in
    sum := !sum +. (-1.) ** m /. (2. *. m +. 1.)
  done;
  4.0 *. !sum
```

But, in the code above creating a `ref` to the `sum` will incur boxing/unboxing on each step, that we can further optimize this code by using `float_ref` [trick](https://janestreet.github.io/ocaml-perf-notes.html):

```
type float_ref = { mutable value : float}

let pi_approx n =
  let sum = {value = 0.} in
  for m = 0 to n - 1 do
    let m = float_of_int m in
    sum.value <- sum.value +. (-1.) ** m /. (2. *. m +. 1.)
  done;
  4.0 *. sum.value
```

### Scoreboard

```
for-loop (with float_ref) : 1.0
non-local recursion       : 0.89
local recursion           : 0.86
Pascal's version          : 0.77
for-loop (with float ref) : 0.62
array                     : 0.47
original                  : 0.08
```

### Update

I've updated the answer, as I've found a way to give 40% speedup (or 33% in comparison with @Pascal's answer.

Comment: Since the compiler converts the recursive version to an imperative version, it would be interesting to see why the imperative version is slower, but if the difference is very small, it would probably be difficult. I wonder if the use of a reference prevents the compiler from storing the sum in a register, as opposed to the recursive version.

Comment: @Zoyd, I'm assuming that imperative version is no faster due to a [write barrier](http://janestreet.github.io/ocaml-perf-notes.html). Although it is a speculation, since we do not looked at the generated assembler.

Comment: Can you please share the time measurements?  Of course, they differ from machine to machine, but they provide information on relative performance when more than one implementation is run on the same machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add that although floats are boxed in OCaml, **float arrays** are unboxed. Here is a program that builds a float array corresponding to the Leibnitz sequence and uses it to approximate π:

```
open Array

let q_pi_approx n =
  let summand n  =
    let m = float_of_int n
    in (-1.) ** m /. (2. *. m +. 1.) in
  let a = Array.init n summand in
  Array.fold_left (+.) 0. a

let n = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1);;
Printf.printf "%F\n" (4. *. (q_pi_approx n));;
```

Obviously, it is still slower than a code that doesn't build any data structure at all. Execution times (the version with array is the last one):

```
time ./v1 10000000
3.14159275359

real    0m2.479s
user    0m2.380s
sys 0m0.104s

time ./v2 10000000
3.14159255359

real    0m0.402s
user    0m0.400s
sys 0m0.000s

time ./a 10000000
3.14159255359

real    0m0.453s
user    0m0.432s
sys 0m0.020s
```